# Definite integral involving sinc functions

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform, convolution

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{sinc}(8t)\mathrm{sinc^2(t)}\cos(8\pi t) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
assuming that the sinc function is defined as:
$$
\mathrm{sinc}(t) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t} \ &x \neq 0\\
1 &x = 0
\end{cases} 
$$
I have tried to solve the problem using Fourier transforms and their properties, so:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{sinc}(8t)\mathrm{sinc^2(t)}\cos(8\pi t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}(0) = X(0)
$$
Focusing on the integrand $x$, it can be written as:
$$
x(t) = \mathrm{sinc}(8t)\cos(8\pi t)\mathrm{sinc^2(t)} = \left[\mathrm{sinc}(8t)\frac{e^{j8\pi t} + e^{-j8\pi t}}{2} \right] \mathrm{sinc^2(t)} = x_1(t)x_2(t)
$$
where:
\begin{align*}
x_1(t) &= \frac{e^{j8\pi t}}{2}\mathrm{sinc}(8t) + \frac{e^{-j8\pi t}}{2}\mathrm{sinc}(8t) \\
x_2(t) &= \mathrm{sinc}^2(t)
\end{align*}
Using the convolution property of the Fourier transform and writing the transforms with capital letters, it is:
$$
X(f) = X_1(f) * X_2(f)
$$
The transform of $x_1$ is given by:
$$
X_1(f) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{8}\mathrm{rect}_8(f-4) + \frac{1}{8}\mathrm{rect}_8(f+4) \right] = \frac{1}{16}\left[ \mathrm{rect}_8(f-4) + \mathrm{rect}_8(f+4) \right]
$$
The transform of $x_2$ is given by:
$$
X_2(f) = \mathrm{tri}_1(f)
$$
The transform of $x$ can be written as:
$$
X(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X_1(\xi) X_2(f-\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi
$$
which, evaluated in $f = 0$, gives:
$$
X(0) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X_1(\xi) X_2(-\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{16}\left[ \mathrm{rect}_8(\xi-4) + \mathrm{rect}_8(\xi+4) \right] \mathrm{tri}_1(-\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi
$$
Since the tri function is even, the last equation can be rewritten as:
$$
X(0) = \frac{1}{16}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[ \mathrm{rect}_8(\xi-4) + \mathrm{rect}_8(\xi+4) \right] \mathrm{tri}_1(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi
$$
In order to evaluate the integral,
[I have plotted the functions which define the integrand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tavj3.png), keeping in mind that I have to use the following definition of rect:
$$
\mathrm{rect}_\Delta(t) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\left|t\right| < \Delta/2 \\
0 &\left|t\right| > \Delta/2
\end{cases}
$$
Since this definition of rect doesn't include a value for $t = \pm \Delta/2$, I don't know how to evaluate the integral. Looking at the figure, where it looks like the two rects *don't* intersect *properly*, I'd say that the integrand is zero and so the answer should be zero, however I'm not sure about the rigor of this solution: can I really say that the intersection is null or should I see the sum of rects as a big rect whose base goes from -8 to 8?

I have tried to check my calculations solving the integral with Wolfram and I have noticed that I get two different answers ($A$) if I write the integrand as a product of sincs and cos ($A = 0$) or as a product of sins (sinc in explicit form) and cos ($A = 1/16$), probably due to the way sinc and rect are defined in Wolfram.

```
integral_(-∞)^∞ sinc(8 t) sinc(t)^2 cos(8 π t) dt = 0

integral_(-∞)^∞ (sin(8 π t) (sin(π t)/(π t))^2 cos(8 π t))/(8 π t) dt = 1/16 = 0.0625
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $I$ as the integral of interest

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}(8t)\text{sinc}^2(t)\cos(8\pi t)\,dt\\\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}(16t)\text{sinc}^2(t)\,dt
\end{align}$$

Now, the Fourier transforms of $f(t)=\text{sinc}(16 t)$ and $g(t)=\text{sinc}^2(t)$ are given respectively by

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1{32}\left(\text{sgn}(\omega+16\pi)-\text{sgn}(\omega-16\pi)\right)
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi -\omega}{2\pi}\left(\text{sgn}(\omega+2\pi)-\text{sgn}(\omega-2\pi)\right)
\end{align}$$

---

Using the convolution theorem, we find that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ \text{sgn}(\omega +16\pi)-\text{sgn}(\omega-16\pi)}{32} \left( \frac{2\pi -\omega}{2\pi}\left(\text{sgn}(\omega+2\pi)-\text{sgn}(\omega-2\pi)\right)\right)\,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac1{64\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{2\pi -\omega}{2\pi}\,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac1{16}
\end{align}$$

---

Note that WolframAlpha defines the sinc funtion as

$$\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ne \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$

When accounting for this differnce in definition WA retunrs the correct answer (See [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+sinc%288+pi+x%29+sinc%5E2%28pi+x%29+cos%288+pi+x%29+from+-infinity+to+infinity)) of $1/16$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, introducing the function $\mathrm{sinc}(16t)$ I get $X(0) = \frac{1}{16}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{rect}_{16}(\xi)\mathrm{tri}_1(\xi)\, \mathrm{d}\xi = \frac{1}{16}$, however I am not able to understand yet why I get $X(0) = 0$ in Wolfram if I write the sinc function in its implicit form and the same happens in MATLAB if I write the sinc in its explicit form.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: With WolframAlpha, I get (See [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+sinc%288+pi+x%29+sinc%5E2%28pi+x%29+cos%288+pi+x%29+from+-infinity+to+infinity)) the correct answer.  Note that the sinc funciotn is defined there as $\text{sinc(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, without the $\pi$ in the argument.

Comment: Hi Mark ! You type too fast for the old man.

Comment: Thank you very much, so it was a problem of definitions in Wolfram; I have tried again the computation in MATLAB (it looks like I made some mistakes earlier) and I have got the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: You're more than welcome.

Comment: @claudeleibovici Hi Claude.  How are you my friend?

Answer (score 3):

*Hoping that it could help you*

Using the definition $\text{sinc}(t)=\frac{\sin (\pi  t)}{\pi  t}$ you face the problem of
$$I=\int \frac{\sin ^2(\pi  t) \sin (8 \pi  t) \cos (8 \pi  t)}{8 \pi ^3 t^3}\,dt=\int \frac{\sin ^2(\pi  t) \sin (16 \pi  t)}{16 \pi ^3 t^3}\,dt$$ Using multiple angle formulae, we have
$$I=\frac 1{64\pi^2t}\Big[7 \cos (14 \pi  t)-16 \cos (16 \pi  t)+9 \cos (18 \pi  t) \Big]+$$ $$\frac 1{128\pi^3t^2}\Big[\sin (14 \pi  t)-2 \sin (16 \pi  t)+\sin (18 \pi  t)\Big]+$$
$$\frac 1{32\pi}\Big[49\, \text{Si}(14 \pi  t)-128\, \text{Si}(16 \pi  t)+81 \,\text{Si}(18 \pi  t)\Big]$$ Only the last term remains when using the bounds and the result
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin ^2(\pi  t) \sin (8 \pi  t) \cos (8 \pi  t)}{8 \pi ^3 t^3}\,dt=\frac 1{16}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be any positive value greater than or equal to $1$.

Using contour integration, we have

$$ \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(at) \operatorname{sinc}^{2}(t) \cos(a \pi t) \, \mathrm dt &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(a \pi t) \sin^{2}(\pi t)\cos(a \pi t)}{a \pi^{3} t^{3}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2 a \pi t) \sin^{2}(\pi t)}{2a \pi^{3} t^{3}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \Im  \, \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i 2a \pi t} \sin^{2}(\pi t)}{2a \pi^{3} t^{3}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \Im \, i \pi \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{e^{i 2a \pi z} \sin^{2}(\pi z)}{2a \pi^{3} z^{3}}, 0 \right] \tag{1}\\ &=   \Im \, i \pi \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^{i 2a \pi z} }{2a \pi} \left(\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} \right)^{2} \\ &= \frac{1}{2a} . \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ If $a \ge 1$, then $|e^{i 2a \pi z} \sin^{2}(\pi z)| $ is small in the upper half-plane.